# jquery form validation: validation script specified externally

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

i have a jquery form validation in the master page and it works fine and i got that working from this article: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=310

my question is: if i place the .js to external and add a reference to my page then its not working... it says object expected

here is how i have done:

in my content page (i am using master page, asp.net )

add in my content page:

```
<script src="myform_validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {       
        ValidateMe(this);
    });
</script>
```

below is in the external .js file:

```
 function ValidateMe() { 

            $("#aspnetForm").validate({
                rules: 
                {
                        <%=TextBox1.UniqueID %>: 
                        {
                            maxlength:1,
                            //minlength: 12,
                            required: true
                        },
                         <%=TextBox2.UniqueID %>: 
                        {
                            minlength: 12,
                            required: true
                        },
                         <%=TextBox3.UniqueID %>: 
                        {
                            minlength: 12,
                            required: true
                        }//,
//                    
                },          
                messages: 
                    {
                        <%=TextBox1.UniqueID %>:
                        { 
                            required: "Enter your firstname", 
                            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters") 
                        },
                         <%=TextBox2.UniqueID %>:
                        { 
                            required: "Please enter a valid email address",
                              minlength: "Please enter a valid email address"
                        }  ,
                          <%=TextBox3.UniqueID %>:
                        { 
                            required: "Enter your firstname", 
                            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters") 
                        }

                     }    , 


          success: function(label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("checked");
        }

        });
        } ;
```

Comment: Did you include the jquery reference in your external js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect its because your server tags (`<%=TextBox1.UniqueID%>`) are not being processed by the server.  By default IIS does not process .js files.

Answer (score 1):

1. For starters try to always use the
   same identified for jQuery.
   Sometimes you use **jQuery** and
   sometimes **$**, I would recommend
   to use **$** all the way but just
   because its shorter and well known
   (and im lazy ;) ).
2. You are passing this into the
   external ValidateMe function, even
   though it has no parameters. Are you
   sure you extracted the function
   properly?
3. And always make sure all js files
   are referenced before you start
   using functions within them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but i dont see where i am using JQuery and i also prefer to use $ :)
about your #2) i was trying different method and non of them works, with passing parameters and without passing parameters

Comment: @Abu - for example at: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")

Answer (score 1):

Why are you attempting to put the javascript into an external file? The script is specific to controls on the page, so leave it there. Otherwise you are adding latency to the page by requiring an extra file download.

Comment: @Daniel, the reason i am doing is because it will be so much clutter on the page and just wanted to keep neat and simple.